# Populate Multi-person field using an Input field in Microsoft Flow

Tags: flow, person, multi-select

Is it possible to populate a multi-user Person SharePoint field using the "Email" type input within Microsoft Flow?  That is, when triggering the Flow, a user is prompted to specify one or more people and these people should then be shown on the SharePoint item.

So far I've tried the following in the "Update Item" SharePoint action in Flow:

- Update person field using a delimited string: `"user1@office365service.com;user2@office365service.com;"`
- Update person field using a delimited claims string: `"i:0#.f|membership|user1@office365service.com;i:0#.f|membership|user2@office365service.com;"`
- Updating person field using an array variable, which contains either plain email or claims formatted values.

Each time, the Update Item action is itself 'Successful', but the multi-person field is still shown as "[]".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an array like below and pass you the multi valued person field,

'''{
  "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|@{items('Apply_to_each')?['mail']}",
  "Email": "@{items('Apply_to_each')?['mail']}"
}  '''

The above code is not the exact working code, I have taken that piece from the below url. You have to form your array with user details in the above format and append to array and that array you can use it to person field,

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/update-multi-values-people-picker-field-in-power-automatemicrosoft-flow/

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Multiple-people-picker-values-in-FLOW/td-p/257018